# How can I change the color of a map fragment (inside a linear layout) when it is touched/clicked?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

Currently, I have a map fragment inside of a linear layout, which serves as the maps "border;" however, I want to handle clicks on the map so that when the map is touched, not necessarily clicked, the linear layout's stroke changes color.  I tried using an motion event for the map fragment on click listener, but it throws the following error: "Error:(147, 87) error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method onMapClick(LatLng) in OnMapClickListener."

Thanks in advance,

Jacob

Here is the java I'm trying to use:

```
mapFragment.getMap().setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng x, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    infoButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b20000"));


                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    infoButton.setBackground((Drawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.buttonshape2));
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the api and your error,  you need to include  onMapClick(LatLng) in the listener.

```
@Override
Public void onMapClick(LatLng point){
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener has abstract method for which you must provide implementation

```
public abstract void onMapClick (LatLng point)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html

Don't see any method which gives access to the MotionEvent.